# Magento newsletter goal set-up Google Analytics

Tags: newsletter, google-analytics

How can I set up the goal in Google Analytics for a successful newsletter subscription?
The problem here is that this successful newsletter subscription doesn't render a individual URL (so, nothing like: `www.xx.com/thankyou` or something, in which case I could have used 'thankyou'). It just returns the homepage (`www.xx.com`) with a message on it that subscription has been successful.

I googled quite a bit and more people seem to have encoutered this issue, but I haven't managed to work it out..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best option but what you could do is simply set the referrer url on the newsletter button.

```
Mage::getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', array('referer' => Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($this->getUrl("frontname/controller/function"))))
```

Then this will redirect the user to your url after the action on the newsletter has been performed.

Obviously there are a few issues with this, firstly it appears that the controller simply sets a message on the session when an error happens and also it is taking the user away from the original page, but purely from a google tracking point of view this would work.